# "Adding" GROUP BY's and ORDER BY's in one query instead of separate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rollup, grouping-sets

I have a base query that has a few variations, all of them are different from each other in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

These are the variations:

```
SELECT SUM(col_a) AS "col_a", SUM(col_b), AS "col_b", SUM(col_c) as "col_c"
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col_a

SELECT SUM(col_a) AS "col_a", SUM(col_b), AS "col_b", SUM(col_c) as "col_c"
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col_a, col_b
ORDER BY col_a

SELECT SUM(col_a) AS "col_a", SUM(col_b), AS "col_b", SUM(col_c) as "col_c"
FROM my_table
GROUP BY col_a, col_b, col_c
ORDER BY col_a, col_b
```

Is it possible to do it in same query? Or I should get the base data and sum it server side/client side?

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL (which was the original question) you can do it in the same query using WITH ROLLUP:

```
select sum(col_a) as col_a, sum(col_b) as col_b, sum(col_c) as col_c, count(*),
    case (col_a is not null) + (col_b is not null) + (col_c is not null) when 3 then 'col_a,col_b,col_c' when 2 then 'col_a,col_b' when 1 then 'col_a' end grouped_by
from my_table
group by col_a, col_b, col_c with rollup
having grouped_by is not null
order by grouped_by,col_a, col_b, col_c
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9vWpUTHs)

Comment: I am going to test it, never used `with_rollup` before. WIll update, thank you

Comment: @B.DLiroy updated to exclude the grand total row and designate which grouping each row has (this only works if you do not have null values for these columns, do you?)

Comment: Oh there are a few nulls. I might update the table to default to 0's instead of nulls then. What happens in case the `(col_a is not null)` meets a null? I might try to do a case within a case (so in case it's null, make it 0). Also, since I need the results separately. Is there a way to "detect" which rows are for which query? Because although I want a single query (to prevent many DB queries), I still need the results separately

Comment: Basically it can't tell if the null is because it is a roll-up or is the actual data.  What does `select version();` show?  You may be able to use a `grouping` function to check what is rolled up instead

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, it's not `mysql`, it's ms sql server. Is the version still matter or it's all bad? Will replacing default values to 0 instead of null be better in this case?

Comment: I thought sql server didn't support with roll-up at all.  I could be wrong though.  You could do a union, but that won't be more efficient than just separate queries.

Comment: I see there is a group by rollup feature, but I don't know how it works

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP` for this. The former is more flexible, if a little more verbose.

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(col_a) AS col_a,
  SUM(col_b) AS col_b,
  SUM(col_c) as col_c
FROM my_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (col_a),
    (col_a, col_b),
    (col_a, col_b, col_c)
)
ORDER BY col_a, col_b, col_c;
```

To identify the rolled up rows, you can do something like this

```sql
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(col_b) = 0 AND GROUPING(col_c) = 0
         THEN 'By A, B, C'
       WHEN GROUPING(col_b) = 0
         THEN 'By A, B'
       ELSE   'By A'
       END AS GroupingType,
  SUM(col_a) AS col_a,
  SUM(col_b) AS col_b,
  SUM(col_c) as col_c
FROM my_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (col_a),
    (col_a, col_b),
    (col_a, col_b, col_c)
)
ORDER BY col_a, col_b, col_c;
```